# Switching between video tracks on a video element

Tags: javascript, html5-video

I'm wondering if it's possible to switch between video tracks on a given < video > element

```
<video id='vid'></video>
```

I was able to add multiple video tracks to the stream using:

```
vid.captureStream().addTrack(added track)
```

Essentially I was able to add multiple video tracks. But as soon as
the element contains more than one video track, no video will play.
If I remove the extra tracks, the video will play the added tracks.

I tried fooling around with the `track.enabled` property but it doesn't seem to do anything.

The idea is I want to load a bunch of tracks initially and switch between them. Possible?

It is essential that no video tracks are added and removed, only initially loading them.

Comment: You could try loading the files into Arrays (buffers) and then loading one of these Arrays as `.src` whenever needed, would that be a possible solution for you...? If you can get the loading into Arrays part done I can advise how to convert Array into Blob for playback.

Comment: Thanks but the idea is I can't change the src, that's why I'm using the tracks. However there isn't much information about what these tracks do and how they work. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/VideoTrack

Comment: **(1)** The only other option is to use **MediaSource Extensions** (MSE) to dynamically feed bytes (from Arrays) of video data to the same/one video tag.... **(2)** These "tracks" are not supported by major browsers (only Safari and obsolete Internet Explorer). I tried the audio tracks a few years back (playing one video but switching the language audio tracks... it never worked).

Comment: Thanks for the perspective. It's not a bad idea. I've had some success with tracks but the results are random at best.